What does “user was removed” mean?
I saw a notice in my Achievements suggesting that I was removed as a user from the Bricks group. As far as I can tell this isn’t true, but I’m still wondering what to make of the notification. Can anyone shed light on why i received the notification or what it means? See screenshot.


This is one of the most demotivational features of StackExchange for me.  I see the need for it, but it doesn't work out too nicely sometimes.  On a few sites I don't have any knowledge to make answers, but I've made tons of edits.  So SE comes along and removes 10-50 rep because of a user deletion.  That's 5-25 edits that I wrote and got approved by somebody too.  The reviewers don't lose credit, but the writer of the edit doesn't.  Oh well.

It means that another user that voted on one of your questions or answers was removed from the site. When this happens, the system reverts all the reputation changes that happened when that user upvotes or downvotes on posts.
There are a number of reasons that an account might be removed ranging from the user requesting it themselves, through to the account being linked to spamming or sock puppets.
For more details, please see this help topic: Why do I have a reputation change on my reputation page that says 'User was removed'?
